# Can Captain Marvel travel through space using a space portal?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, captain-marvel

In the movie *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos was able to travel from planet to planet very quickly using space portals that were created with the Space Stone.

> Since Captain Marvel is directly linked to the Space Stone, does this mean that she can also travel from planet to planet using space portals and thus does not have to fly to planets?

I am referring to the Captain Marvel in the MCU.

Comment: Seeing how Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver derive their powers from the mind stone, and besides SW's power to brainwash and trick people with illusions, it doesn't look like people's abilities are directly related to the stone's original power.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie yet; however if she does derive her powers from the infinity stones that would be a major departure from the comics. Originally, she got her cosmic powers from a Kree device. And if your title is a spoiler you may want to move it into the question and hide it with the spoiler tags.

Comment: @djm It's still Kree tech that gave her her powers, technically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *Captain Marvel* and *Avengers: Endgame*, we never see Captain Marvel use the same sort of portal-like travel as Thanos does.

However, we do see instances where she appears to travel very quickly:

> At the end of the movie, Captain Marvel and the Kree cruiser with the Skrulls in it zip off into space without using the Jump Gate system. Unless the Skrulls were going to take a very (very very) long time to get to their new home, Captain Marvel would have to be helping them to travel much faster than light.

and

> In the mid-credits scene, Captain Marvel appears right behind the Avengers that are examining Fury's pager just after it turns off. Similarly, in *Avengers: Endgame*, she takes just 23 days to locate the *Benatar* in deep space and seems to return it to Earth soon after that. No matter how much time it took in total to get back to Earth, she must have been traveling much faster than light.

So, can she travel quickly? **Yes**. Can she use portals? **Probably not**.

Comment: She has the plans for Mar-Vell's light speed engine, doesn't she?

Comment: @Wossname Most likely, but there's no indication that she built it in the movie. Additionally, she's flying beside or in-front of the ship when the event in the first spoiler occurs, so she has to be traveling that quickly as well. I think the simplest explanation is that she can just fly very quickly.

Comment: I guess my only thought with your second spoiler is that it seems that Banner and the remaining avengers seem to have been messing around with the pager for awhile since they mention having to bypass the battery system and other technical lingo that would make me assume it took some time to work on. The other timeline element I'd mention is they were all in Wakanda when the snap happened so we have no idea what time frame it took for them to get back to New York and find Fury's car and pager when they didn't know about it.

Comment: @drakonusrenovotio “we have no idea what time frame it took for them to get back to New York” — very true, although I like to think they all sort of stacked themselves on Thor's shoulders (presumably with puny Banner desperately clinging onto Nat's hand at the top) and rode the Rainbow Bridge there, before he went off with Noble Rabbit to enlist the help of Beta Ray Bill. We'll know whether I'm right in four weeks!